# Laravel migration: Using storedAs() (generated colum) with subtime() MySQL function

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.5, calculated-columns, laravel-migrations

this is my `up()` method in the migration

```
$table->dateTimeTz('from');
$table->time('expire_by_time')->default('0:30:00');

$expression = 'subtime(\'from\', \'expire_by_time\')';
$table->dateTimeTz('expire_at')->storedAs($expression);
```

What I have is an event that starts at `from` but I want it to 'expire' 30min (or an hour, or 50hours ...) before it starts. Later in my code I can use this newly generated `expire_at` column for displaying or sorting.

However this is not working for some reason and I keep getting `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for `expired_at`column

```
+-------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id    | from                | expire_by_time | expire_at           |
+-------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| 11111 | 2019-09-29 12:00:00 | 00:30:00       | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

What am I doing (getting) wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to escape characters. This:

```
$expression = 'subtime(\'from\', \'expire_by_time\')';
```

should be this:

```
$expression = 'subtime(`from`, `expire_by_time`)';
```

and now I get this:

```
+-------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id    | from                | expire_by_time | expire_at           |
+-------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| 11111 | 2019-09-29 12:00:00 | 00:30:00       | 2019-09-29 11:30:00 |
+-------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```